# is yardstick from tidymodels good statistical tool to evaluate metrics like RO, AUC and RMSE

Tags: algorithm, model, metrics, hyperparameters

I want to evaluate metric based on interface modeling similar to caret. I used caret for XGBoost, randomFOrest and some time Keras for statistical metric.So I never used tidymodels for metrics evaluation. I want to find the same metric I wrote in title with tidymodels too

I tried with caret mlr3 also and now want to try with tidymodels to check different accuracy metrics. Is it worth checking evaluation metric based on it ? Also I'm expecting to achieve cross validation technique, model comparison, and metric computations ( F1 score, ROC AUC, RMSE, MAE)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of metrics, grouped by type, on the [yardstick reference page](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/index.html). There is pretty good parity with caret (not sure about mlr3 though).

There is some good reading about using them in [chapter 9](https://www.tmwr.org/performance) of the tidymodels book as well as on [tidymodels.org](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/resampling/#performance) and the [workshop notes](https://workshops.tidymodels.org/archive/2023-09-posit-conf/) (such as [these slides](https://workshops.tidymodels.org/archive/2023-09-posit-conf/intro-04-evaluating-models.html#/title-slide)).